# Parsing saml token with node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, saml

I found a node.js package to parse SAML tokens:

https://github.com/leandrob/saml20

Here's a snippet of the configuration code:

```
saml.validate(rawAssertion, options, function(err, profile) {
    // err
    var claims = profile.claims; // Array of user attributes;
    var issuer = profile.issuer: // String Issuer name.
});
```

However, I'm not sure where the `rawAssertion` parameter comes from or is defined. Is it part of the http request? And if so, which attribute is it?

Additional context - I need this because I am building a node.js app that will use Active Directory Federation Services for authentication purposes.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is a part of a POST the identity provider issues back to your app. Formally, when your app redirects to the provider and the provider validates the credentials, it returns a form with `action` pointing back to your app and a tiny javascript that causes the form to be POSTed. The POSTed body contains the token in one of fields (depends on whether SAML 1 or 2 is used).

Example tokens are here

https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php

this is what you extract from the POST and feed to the saml20 module.